# How to locate CSS pseudo elements？

Tags: python, css, selenium

selenium can't locate the element.

my code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time


driver=webdriver.Chrome()               
driver.get('http://www.christies.com/lotfinder/searchresults.aspx?&searchtype=p&action=paging&searchFrom=header&lid=1&entry=manjusri&pg=all')       
time.sleep(5)                           

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('form.fastSignup> div').click()
```

the imgs of page is here:

[image]

Comment: pseudo element in not a part of the Dom, it's added with CSS

Comment: I want to use selenium to close the registration window，I tried many times but fail, is there any other ways to close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not handle CSS pseudo-elements as they are not a part of DOM and thus cannot be located anyway... According to provided screenshot required element located inside an `iframe` so you need to switch to that `iframe` first:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("signupFrame")
driver.find_element_by_id("close_signup").click()
```